# Nginx redirects inconsistent across browsers

Tags: redirect, nginx, browser

I have a top-level domain. Let's call it `example.com`. I also have three subdomains: `www.example.com`, `app.example.com` and `static.app.example.com`.

I want `example.com` to redirect to `www.example.com`.
I also want all http traffic to redirect to https while preserving the domain and the path.

These are my nginx config files (sorry, it's a bit long):

```
###############  app.example.com ###################

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name app.example.com;
    return 301 https://app.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    include snippets/ssl-example.com.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    server_name app.example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    location /assets {
        alias /var/www/exampleapp/dist/public;
    }

    location /.well-known {
        alias /var/www/example/.well-known;
    }
}

###############  static.app.example.com ###################

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name static.app.example.com;
    return 301 https://static.app.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    include snippets/ssl-example.com.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    server_name static.app.example.com;

    location / {
        alias /var/www/exampleapp/public/;
    }

    location /.well-known {
        alias /var/www/example/.well-known;
    }
}

###############  www.example.com & example.com ###################

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name www.example.com;
    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    include snippets/ssl-example.com.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    server_name example.com;
    return 301 $scheme://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    include snippets/ssl-example.com.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    server_name www.example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5500;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    location /assets {
        alias /var/www/example/dist/public;
    }

    location /.well-known {
        alias /var/www/example/.well-known;
    }
}
```

Now here's the weird part. This works perfectly fine on desktop chrome and firefox. But on mobile chrome and edge, it does something strange. It redirects from `example.com` to `app.example.com`. I can't figure out what it is. I've tried clearing the browser cache and playing with nginx settings but nothing helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a server for `example.com` on port 80. So, any browser that connects using `http` to `example.com` will use the default server (which happens to be the `app.example.com` server block).

You should change the last `http` `server` block to:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name www.example.com example.com;
    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: I actually posted an answer to my own question a few minutes earlier than you did, but since SO doesn't let me accept my own answer (at least not for another two days), I'll just accept yours. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

So the browser inconsistency turned out to be just cache. Even though I cleared the browser cache, it was still caching the 301 redirects. Apparently the best way to bust a redirect cache is to append a random query string to the url.

In terms of the wrong redirect, a friend pointed out that if you don't specify a handler for a naked domain, then the first subdomain is used which is what was happening here for http requests. https was fine as I was listening to that. I just added another server block on port 80 for the naked domain. And that solved the problem.